# Let $g(x)= \sup_{|y|> |x|} |f(y)|$ $(x,y \in \mathbb R).$ $|f(x)| \leq |g(x)|$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, real-numbers

Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ be some function. Put $g(x)= \sup_{|y|> |x|} |f(y)|$ $(x,y \in \mathbb R).$

> Is it true that $|f(x)| \leq |g(x)|$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$?

Answer (score 2):

No. Define $f(0) = 1$ and $f(x) = 0$ for $x \ne 0$.
Then $g(x) = 0$ for all $x$ and in particular $|f(0)| = 1 > 0 = |g(0)|$.

(The answer would be yes if $f$ is assumed to be continuous.)

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't see your answer.

Comment: @Soma: No problem, our answers were posted almost simultaneously :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ defined by $f(0)=1$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise. Then by definition $g(x)=0$ for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Then $|f(0)|>|g(0)|$.